# How to unit-test composition of sagas?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, generator, redux-saga

we can compose sagas in that way
https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/blob/5a6db57c77141b85b82aa097933ad687aacff8dc/docs/advanced/ComposingSagas.md

in next example I call "sub-saga" `loadAssets` from `libraryChangeCategory`

```
import * as LibraryActions from 'actions/libraryActions';
import loadAssets from './loadAssets';

export default function* libraryChangeCategory(category) {
    yield put(LibraryActions.librarySetCategory(category));

    yield put(LibraryActions.librarySetLoading());
    yield* loadAssets();
    yield put(LibraryActions.libraryResetLoading());
}
```

And test two first yield is OK.

```
import libraryChangeCategory from 'sagas/library/changeCategory';
const generator = libraryChangeCategory(LibraryCategories.Backgrounds);

let next;

it('should set category', () => {
    next = generator.next();

    expect(next.value).toEqual(
        put(LibraryActions.librarySetCategory( LibraryCategories.Backgrounds )));
});
```

But I don't want to test here `loadAssets` generator.
I just want to mock it.
But how ? It seems that it is not possible ?

```
function* mockGen() {
    yield;
}
let loadAssets = libraryChangeCategory.__get__('loadAssets');

// don't work
loadAssets.__Rewire__(loadAssets.__get__('loadAssets'), mockGen);

// don't work too
spyOn(loadAssets, 'loadAssets').and.callFake(function(st) {
    yield;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I found solution, instead of calling generator directly, you can call sub-saga via `redux-saga.call`, i.e. you should

`yield* loadAssets();`

change to

`yield call(loadAssets);`

and than unit test will be just

```
  import loadAssets from 'sagas/library/loadAssets';

  it('should call sub-saga', () => {
    next = generator.next();

    expect(next.value).toEqual(call(loadAssets));
  });
```